# Use a while loop to display letters entered by a user in vertical order?

Tags: java, words

I'm trying to create a script that will ask a user to input a word and then display back the letters entered by the user in vertical order.  The problem is that I'm required to use a while loop, any ideas??????

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VerticalWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


               System.out.println("Enter A word");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


                String word = scan.nextLine();

                for(char a : word.toCharArray())
                {
                   System.out.println("Letter: " + a); 
            }
    }
}
```

I have tried that code, and it works but its not a while loop ^

Comment: *"The problem is that I'm required to use a while loop"* Why is using a while loop a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Enter A word");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = 0;

String word = scan.nextLine();

while(a < word.length){
    System.out.println(word.charAt(a));
    a++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, we'll try that

Comment: why do you want to make it "while loop" by the way.?

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerticalWords {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter A word: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;

    String word = scan.nextLine();

    while(a < word.length())
    {
        System.out.println("Letter: " + (word.charAt(a)));
        a++;
    }


}
```

}